# Types à la Curry in Simply Typed Lamba Calculus

Tags: haskell, type-inference, lambda-calculus

I'm writing a toy theorem prover with Haskell following the model of L.Paulson; one of the creators of Isabelle.

According to one of his articles, a theorem prover may be built with the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus. I created the data type with

```
data TLTerms = Var Id
| Const Id Types
| Lambda Id Types TLTerms
| Comp TLTerms TLTerms
deriving (Eq)
```

i.e. following types à la Church. However, I would like to implement the type system à la Curry. Maybe it is not the best of the systems for this purpose; but I want to try the Curry-style in order to judge which style is better. The first problem is type inference.

```
checkType :: TypeContext -> TLTerms -> Maybe Types
-- Given a context, if i is in the context
-- i has its type assigned in the context
checkType ls (Var i) = case lookup i ls of
    Just t -> Just t
    Nothing -> Nothing
-- the constants come predefined by the alphabet
checkType _ (Const _ typ) = Just typ
-- the abstractions have type sigma -> tau
checkType ls (Lambda x typ terms) = do
    t <- checkType ((x,typ): ls) terms
    return $ Arrow typ t

checkType ls (Comp term1 term2) = do
    x <- checkType ls term1
    y <- checkType ls term2
    case (x,y) of
        (Arrow a b, c) -> if a==c then Just b else Nothing
        _ -> Nothing
```

I took the code from another related question. I surely believe there's a more elegant algorithm to verify if a lambda-term is well-typed. My questions are:

1. which parts should be changed/added/removed (apart from deleting the
   type argument in abstractions);
2. which error monad should be better:
   `Maybe` or `Either` or another (I want to return a value which means
   failure);
3. or if I should create another function from scratch.

PD: I'm new to Haskell, although I've written example programs like dual numbers or power series. Just to explain my level of knowledge in this subject.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake and haven't finished my question. Now it's complete.

Comment: Whatever the question is, that's not the equality you want.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: I think that is a question that begs a paper-length answer ... and all of your specific questions 1-3 seems to be more about opinions(?)

Comment: btw: I think @user1666959 is talking about the `deriving (Eq)` on your `TLTerms` data-type - this will most likely not be the equality your are expecting on lambda-terms

Comment: Changing from types à la Church (explicit) to types à la Curry (implicit) is non trivial. You can not hope to remove something from the existing type checking algorithm and obtain a type inference algorithm. Inference is more complex than checking. I'd suggest you look up the [Hindley-Milner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type system and its algorithm W to see how to implement it.

Comment: Check out this blog post on implementing type inference for STLC: https://flippac.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/the-simply-typed-lambda-calculus-with-constraints/